# React Native Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've add launchscreen to my React-Native app with XCode, but i've this error : `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

And in the log :

```
2018-02-08 11:52:48.552534+0100 projectName[16782:2054906] [ApplicationLifecycle] Windows were created before application initialzation completed. This may result in incorrect visual appearance.
2018-02-08 11:52:48.553602+0100 orphoz[16782:2054906] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2018-02-08 11:52:49.187017+0100 orphoz[16782:2054906] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/novaway/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B9A9FDD9-0FF0-4321-A0F4-A6BEB950829B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D1D3706C-5AD5-4B21-BE12-833D95FAD49E/projectName.app> (loaded)' with name 'LaunchScreen''
```

If i remove my launchscreen, i can start my React Native, i don't understand the problem :)

Anyone have idea ?

Thank you !